# Do Anyone know a fast, easy, portable, lighweight way to create a Browser Only Application?

Tags: browser, desktop

Im Making a Game based in php but i'd like to create too an desktop app for it, i would be just a window of defined size and unresizable. In Fact it would be a browser without any button, just a window that takes to a website. Its Pretty easy and simple. Anyonw knows a portable (no need to install, avaiable in Linux amc if possible). lighweight(very VERY small not more than 2 Megabytes.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking to create a [site-specific browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Site-specific_browser).

Comment: Thats Quite Right it! Thanks ill be looking for that resources